# CheckBox - Once Checked you cannot uncheck ? - GoogleAppsScript / GoogleSheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible to code a checkbox that once checked it stays checked ?

My code would run again if a person checked - then unchecked - then accidently checked again, something I dont want to happen.

Here is the code

```
  function onEdit(e) {

  AddPalletCount(e)
  AddCheckBox(e)
  }

 function AddCheckBox(e){
 var row = e.range.getRow();
 var col = e.range.getColumn();

 if(col === 2 && row > 2 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "PREPSHEET"){

  e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,4).setValue(new Date());
  e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,3).setValue("Done");

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var activeRange = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.CHECKBOX;
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireCheckbox().build();
  var range = sheet.getRange(activeRange.getRow(), 5);
  range.setDataValidation(rule);
  }}
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: If you are still looking for the solution of your issue, can I ask you about your question? About `My code would run again if a person checked - then unchecked - then accidently checked again, something I dont want to happen.`, in this case, you don't want to make users (except for you) uncheck the checked checkbox. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Tanaike - would it be simpler to just have an alert pop up when box checked and say "are you sure this is right checkbox " - they hit yes and then code runs ? gives them a chance to say "no" and code doesnt run. thank you for answering so many of my questions.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I could understand that you are still looking for the solution of your issue. But I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand whether my understanding for your goal is correct. You don't want to make users (except for you) uncheck the checked checkbox. Is my understanding correct? After I could correctly understand about your goal, I would like to think of about the solution and workaround. I apologize for this.

Comment: Could your this issue be resolved? Or if you have still be looking for the solution, is there anything that I can do for resolving your issue?

Comment: 田池-他の問題が優先されているため、この問題の解決策を見つけるのを延期しました。尋ねていただきありがとうございます。

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could understand about your situation.

Comment: 棚池-私は本当に解決できない問題に悩まされています。できるときは見てもらえないかと思っています。 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dBnpQTigNbw3BmKYLRKyHV9GE2-W571LgSzbetmOpQw/edit#gid=1706938659

Comment: Thank you for replying. I thought your replying might be different from your this question. If you change your question, can you post it as new question? If I misunderstood your replying, I apologize.

Comment: 田池-私は本当に問題を解決しようと思った-私の学習を助けるために。私はすべてを削除し、一度に1つのoneditを追加し始め、問題を修正しました!!!

Comment: Thank you for replying. Where can I see the new question?

Comment: 棚池-あなたが私を手伝ってくれたことに感謝しています。現時点で難しい質問はありませんが、すぐにまた質問します。トム

Comment: Tanaike - Actually if you could have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60374647/modify-code-copy-certain-rows-columns-from-one-spreadsheet-to-another-google

Comment: Thank you for replying. I saw it just now, and I noticed that an answer has already been posted. I think that it will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

**A checkbox that stay's check once it's checked**

It doesn't actually stay checked but once you check and try to uncheck it, it rechecks itself.  It has to change in order to get the onEdit trigger.

Also note that this has to be an installable trigger because simple triggers can't do things that require permission like changing user data.

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast('Entry');//debug
  var sh=e.range.getSheet();
  //var log=Utilities.formatString('oldValue: %s value: %s',e.oldValue,e.value);//debug
  //sh.getRange(sh.getRange(1,9,sh.getLastRow(),1).getValues().filter(String).length+1,9).setValue(log);//debug  
  if(e.range.columnStart==2 && e.range.rowStart>2 && sh.getName()=='DONATIONS RECEIVED') {
    //e.source.toast('Access');//debug
    if(e.oldValue=='true' && e.value=='FALSE') {
      //e.source.toast('SetValue');//debug
      e.range.setValue("TRUE");
    }
  }
}
```

You might wish to keep lines 4 and 5 for future onEdit debugging work as I found them quite helpful in solving this problem.

Comment: Hi Cooper, I have copied your code - tried without a trigger & trigger, but I am able to check and uncheck without code rechecking the box? I have left the comments disabled. is there something I am missing ?

Comment: Cooper see link & (See Cooper File in script editor) https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yoItbv8Puk0oLXw1Y5d6syZsmm-QXjoFg5wOvOM_3bo/edit#gid=1717208027

Comment: @TomSawkins have you installed the trigger?

Comment: @TomSawkins I don't see any sheet called `DONATIONS RECEIVED` in the spreadsheet you shared.

Comment: Sorry iamblichus - changed to prepsheet. will update original post. yes trigger & no trigger