# Modify Code - Copy Certain Rows/Columns From one Spreadsheet to Another - Google Apps Script / Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to incorporate the action the SORT QUERY is doing (above .getRange line of code) in this script. So instead of copying A2:F I would get Column B, C, D, E copied from ONLINESendNewSkusToGID to RECTOONLINE.

```
function CopyNewOnlineSkusFromCDSToGID() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('ONLINESendNewSkusToGID'), true);

  //=SORT(QUERY(JIRA JQL QUERY!A2:F,"SELECT B, C, D, E",0))
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2:F').activate();

  var target = SpreadsheetApp.openById("");
  var source_sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("ONLINESendNewSkusToGID");
  var target_sheet = target.getSheetByName("RECTOONLINE");

  var source_range = source_sheet.getActiveRange();
  var last_row = target_sheet.getLastRow();
  var values = source_range.getValues();
  target_sheet.getRange(last_row + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
}
```

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

Here is the code snippet that copies the columns B to E from one sheet to other. Let me know if this is what you meant to achieve with your question.

```js
function CopyNewOnlineSkusFromCDSToGID() {
  // get spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // get the two desired sheets
  var online = ss.getSheetByName("ONLINESendNewSkusToGID");
  var rect = ss.getSheetByName("RECTOONLINE");
  // get the values of the sheet we want to copy
  var values = online.getRange('B:E').getValues();
  // set the values where we want to paste
  rect.getRange('B:E').setValues(values);
}
```

For more info regarding how to get and set values check out [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()) and [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) respectively. I hope this has helped you, let me know if you need anything else or if you did not understood something.

Comment: Hi Mateo - How can I only select certain columns. I accidently posted wrong range above. So I need A,F,G,D ? I tried different variations of the range but no good. Also there is no openByID in your answer ?